# Making a platinum chain

Tags: jewelry

Thinking about making a platinum chain for myself, just for fun. I plan to do a simple cable chain design, without soldering/welding from a round platinum wire.
Can someone share steps/tools?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi pauld, this is a very broad question: have you already tried some things, or looked up information on how to start your project? On Arts & Crafts we don't offer complete tutorials, but would love to help you when you get stuck somewhere specifically.

Comment: My main concern is 20 Ga wire strong enough so that I don't have to do welding on the jump rings?

Comment: If you don't even know how to make a chain to start with, stop thinking about jumping straight into making one out of expensive materials. It's like thinking you'll win Cupcake Wars when you've never even seen an oven.

Comment: I think this would be a great question if you give it a try and let us help you out with a specific step. There are lots of ways to approach this, and we don't even know what size you're looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

Why not start with a copper chain and see how much fun it is before the expense of platinum ? Copper wire is readily available in giant size range. Platinum wire sizes will be limited. They seem to be in about the same strength range depending on the amount of cold work. When our technicians wound custom heating equipment with platinum wire , there was no problem working it, no special handling (other than to lock up the spool of wire when finished). . I expect you will want annealed wire . If you need to soften it after working it needs only about 1400 F which you can get with a gas stove or propane torch.